# Merging consecutive features based on its properties using recursion in Google Earth Engine Python API

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api, geemap

The HydroSHEDS dataset is a global feature collection of basins at different levels. Each feature has a "NEXT_DOWN" property that helps the navigation within the river network (up and downstream). I want to create all the downstream network starting from one basin. I have the following code in python using recursion (I couldn't reproduce it in GEE).

```py
  def select_next(fc):
      
      next_id = fc.first().get('NEXT_DOWN')
      
      if next_id.getInfo() == 0:
          return fc
      
      next_basin = base_level.filter(ee.Filter.eq('HYBAS_ID', next_id))
          
      return fc.merge(select_next(next_basin))

  geometry = ee.Geometry.Point((-73.83275782083713, 3.532610786227175))
  base_level= ee.FeatureCollection("WWF/HydroSHEDS/v1/Basins/hybas_5")
  main_basin = base_level.filterBounds(geometry)
  
  connected = select_next(main_basin)
```

[image]

Although the code is doing what I want, it is taking so long due to the combination of client-server side methods, and it will take longer if I increase the catchment level. Is there a way to do this without using the `get_info()` method?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you cannot recurse without using client-side code. A workaround to this is to iterate at least as many times as the depth of your recursion. I'm giving an example how this can be done in JavaScript - quicker for me than in Python - but it should translate directly to Python too.

```
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Point([-73.83275782083713, 3.532610786227175])
var base_level = ee.FeatureCollection("WWF/HydroSHEDS/v1/Basins/hybas_5")

// Since we cannot do recursion without getInfo() or evaluate(), 
// iterate a bunch of times, and hope it's enough
var maxSteps = 100
var merged = ee.List(ee.List.sequence(1, maxSteps)
    .iterate( // Follow links of NEXT_DOWN and collect a list of feature collections
      function(i, acc) {
        // Working with feature collections instead of single feature, so that when
        // there is no NEXT_DOWN, we don't have to treat that as a separate condition.
        // It's simply an empty collection.
        acc = ee.List(acc)
        var featureCollection = ee.FeatureCollection(acc.get(acc.size().subtract(1))) // Last in accumulator
        var nextIds = featureCollection.aggregate_array('NEXT_DOWN')
        var nextFeatureCollection = base_level.filter(ee.Filter.inList('HYBAS_ID', nextIds))
        return acc.add(nextFeatureCollection)
      },
      [base_level.filterBounds(geometry)] // The start feature(s)
    ))
  .iterate( // Merge list of feature collections into a single feature collection
    function(featureCollection, acc) {
      return ee.FeatureCollection(acc)
        .merge(ee.FeatureCollection(featureCollection))
    },
    ee.FeatureCollection([])
  )

print(merged)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/0fee9de99173f3252ca2b188a7570d5a

Comment: Thanks Daniel, the workaround is doing what I want... The only thing is that you have to know in advance the number of catchments that can be connected, and this number is higher as the level is increased.

Comment: You can pick a worst-case number, if you got an idea of the maximum number you can get. To be absolutely safe, you could even make that number the size of the initial feature collection.